# Git checking out a specific file only with LF line endings on Windows despite core.autocrlf=true

Tags: git

We have a specific source file (java) in our git repo that is causing us line ending problems.

Our developers all run Windows while our build server runs Linux. The file was checked in with CRLF at some point in the past. We recently introduced Spotless and google-java-format in our build process to enforce code style and it failed when running on our build server.

To fix this I converted the line endings to LF on my Windows box and committed the file. This now works great on our build server, but now every time we check out the file on Windows it checks out with LF line endings and fails the Spotless check.

I have `core.autocrlf=true` on my git config (as verified by `git config --list`). Every other file from the same repo I check out comes out as CRLF on Windows and is correctly converted back to LF in the repo. It's only that one file that's causing problems. This affects our entire team.

I've tried deleting and checking out the file again, even deleting my local repo and cloning the remote from scratch - that one file always comes out as LF on Windows. I've tried various settings in .gitattributes like `*.java text eol=lf` and running `git add --renormalize` but the problem with this file persists. Any ideas why this specific file is having this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the source file had some FIX messages as String literals including SOH (Unicode 0x0001) message delimeters. Although I believe this is valid UTF-8, replacing them with \u0001 escapes seems to have resolved things. This is probably a bug in git's text/binary detection that meant it always considered them binary files and ignored `core.autocrlf`.